# Division by zero factoring problem

Tags: polynomials

Given the fact that the function:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{2x-4}{x-2} = \dfrac{2(x-2)}{x-2} = f(x) = 2$$

Shouldn't $f(x)$ be equal to $2$ in every case, even when $x=2$?

Comment: you likely mean $x=-2$ not $x=2$?

Comment: yes, i changed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing the simplification:
$\frac{2(x-2)}{(x-2)}$ = 2, you are making the claim that $\frac{(x-2)}{(x-2)}$ =1.

This is true for almost any value of x, for example: x= 5
$\frac{(5-2)}{(5-2)}$ = $\frac{3}{3}$ = 1

However, in the case 
$\frac{(2-2)}{(2-2)}$ = $\frac{0}{0}$, which is undefined.

So, that step you do is value for all values of x except x=2.

Answer (score 4):

When you start with a function like $f(x) = \dfrac{2x-4}{x-2}$, you should take note of any restrictions to the domain; in this case, $x \neq 2$.

Now, whatever manipulation you do from this point on has an implicit condition that $x \neq 2$:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \dfrac{2x-4}{x-2}, \quad x \neq 2\\
&= \dfrac{2(x-2)}{x-2}, \quad x \neq 2\\
&= 2, \quad x \neq 2\\
\end{align}
$$

Obviously this is not how we normally write, but the point is that the condition exists from the beginning and doesn't change, even if you cancel some factors along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the way stated your $f(x)$ is *undefined* at $x=2$ because of the zero in the denominator.

There is a continuous extension of $f(x)$, say $c(x)$, which would indeed satisfy $c(2)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is $f(x)=\begin{cases} 2,\  x\neq 2 \\ \text{undefined}, \ x= 2 \end{cases}$

The function is discontinous. The empty circle shows, that the function is undifined at x=2.

The graph is [image]

Comment: But it is a removable discontinuity

Comment: You can remove it. But then you have to define f(x)=2 and $ \mathbb D=\mathbb R$

Comment: Better is $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{2x-4}{x-2},\  x\neq 2 \\ 2, \ x= 2 \end{cases}$$